# PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters NOT getting network printers

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

net 2.0

```
 System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
```

as a service to get list of network printers
but it can only get local printers. i have googled online found some articles on suggesting configure permission with aspnet_wp

I'm just wondering how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as below

**1. Changing the account that ASP.NET runs under.**

The IIS Worker Process runs as Network Service and the ASP.NET Worker Process runs as ASPNET by default. So to access the Installed Printers you have to change it to run under Local System Account.

**2. You can impersonate the asp.net site**

When the IIS Worker Process or the ASP.NET Worker Process starts a Web application, the Web application inherits the identity of the process if impersonation is disabled. (Impersonation is the process of allowing a thread to run under a different account from its process.) However, if impersonation is enabled, each Web application runs under the user account that is authenticated by IIS or the user account that is configured in the Web.config file. Impersonation can be enabled in either of the following two ways in Web.config:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

This allows the Web application to run using the identity that was authenticated by IIS.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="SomeUserAccount" password="SomePassword"/>
```

This allows the Web application to run using a specific identity.

If you have the network printer in `my printers` then it will show up in `Installed printers`.

[Reference link](http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount)